# how to add slash in react router path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have developed a page with react whose route is

`http://example.come/page1`

When the url is loaded I need to append a slash at the end of the url like this

**`http://example.come/page1/`**

My Routes are like this

```
  Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/page1' component={Page1} />
</Router>
```

I tried to change the path directly  to "/page1/" instead of "/page1" but this will not load **`http://example.com/page1`** , It will open only **`http://example.com/page1/`**

I want both the path to load the Page1 component

Comment: User regex in the path

Comment: how will regex change path ?. I will just match the path and load the page

Comment: To use hooks (onEnter and onChange)? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/820#issuecomment-256814655

Comment: @Andre lee its working fine thanks for the link. Can you post it in answer i will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this reply, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/820#issuecomment-256814655

Using `hooks (onEnter and onChange)` with `react-router` v2 or above may achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer will work fine and you will achieve what you need. But there is a catch. Open developers tool and click on network tab then refresh your page....you will see status 302 page redirect from WITHOUT trailing slash path to WITH trailing slash path.

And this is not very good. Atleast set status to 301.

How to set status ? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/458

Comment: Why do I need 301 status ? What is the use of it?

Comment: Using the words "above answer" can be confusing because the order of answers can easily change...

Answer (score 0):

Better resolve the problem from web server, like Nginx, which rewrites the url to add the trailing slash at the end of url.

Comment: A better solution would be to send the users to the correct url in the first place rather than implementing a server side hack to fix a bad link.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this using React Router v6 (2023). This is my solution:

```
function EnforceTrailingSlash() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  if (!pathname.endsWith('/')) {
    return <Navigate to={`${pathname}/`} />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
}

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      element={<EnforceTrailingSlash />}
    >
      ... Your nested routes here ...
    </Route>,
  ),
);
```